# Use Redis and MongoDB ActiveRecords together in Yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, activerecord, redis, yii2

I have MongoDB Active Records (models) and I'm wondering if it's possible to use Redis to automatically set/get/delete the models from Redis's storage.

For example, if I was to run:

```
MyModel::find()->where(["id" => 1])->one();
```

is there a way to make Redis store the result and return it the next time I run that same code?

Also, if I was to update the model with `id = 1`, I'd expect Redis to invalidate the cache.

Is all that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which DB to use. It is about how to implement them. Yii have those two components to set in the config file:

- **db**: a database connection to be used where needed like an [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#active-record) class to represent a model or [Query Builders](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#active-record) or ...
- **cache**: designed to cache things from HTML pages and HTTP requests to [database queries related data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#query-caching).

The good thing about **MongoDB** and **Redis** is that both can be used as a database connection or as a cache component. You may have those configs for example:

```
'components' => [

    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
        'redis' => [
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ]
    ],
],
```

Here, while MongoDB is set as your default database, Redis is only used as a cache component and because all cache components have the same base class [yii\caching\Cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html) they only support [those APIs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-apis). Which should be fine if you are using it for caching proposes only.

Check the [Yii2 Caching Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-overview.html) to see all what you can do with a cache component. A quick example of what you are trying to do may be seen within [@Blizz answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889772/yii2-how-to-cache-active-data-provider) where he did set an SQL query as a dependency to check if cached data should be used or invalidated instead.

In case you need to use the Redis database for more than just caching then you may have those configs instead:

```
'components' => [

    'mongodb' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
    ],

    'redis' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Cache',
        'redis' => 'redis' // id of the connection application component
    ],

],
```

Here we defined 2 databases and selected one of them to be also used as a cache component. It should work the exact same way except that you can also use the Redis database inside your app as a [Redis ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-activerecord.html) or a [Redis ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-activequery.html) class. You will just need to set which DB to be used inside each **model** class as it is done in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254540/yii-2-0-multiple-database-connection).